# Table not populated from json data in variable

Tags: json, bootstrap-table

I am using BoostrapTable in an MVC application.  The controller is returning some data as follows:

```
model.DataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Entities.Select(x => x.DataProperties));
```

My client side looks like this (snippet):

```
<table id="table"></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: '@Model.DataAsJson',
    //url: 'ms.json', 
    columns: [{
        field: 'ClientFileNo',
        title: 'Case No'
    }, {
        field: 'ClientName',
        title: 'Customer Name'
    }]
});
```

The resulting Json looks like this:

```
[{
    "RowNum": "2",
    "ID": "XXX",
    "ClientFileNo": "XXX",
    "Description": "XXX",
    "ClientName": "XXX",
    "TypeDescription": "XXX",
    "PrincipleName": "XXX",
    "Created": "2017-11-08T10:31:23.673Z"
  },
  {
    "RowNum": "3",
    "ID": "XXX",
    "ClientFileNo": "XXX",
    "Description": "XXX",
    "ClientName": "XXX",
    "TypeDescription": "XXX",
    "PrincipleName": "XXX",
    "Created": "2017-11-01T12:29:08.763Z"
  }
]
```

If I paste the result of the SerializeObject() call into a json file and pass to the url property, the table populates as expected.  However, if I use the data property and @Model.DataAsJson then I have **thousands of empty rows in my table with a '-' in each column**.

I have seen a reference to the responseHandler property and I have tried providing a name to my JSON array as follows however it has not fixed my issue:

```
model.DataAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            jsonData = model.Entities.Select(x => x.DataProperties)
        });

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: '@Model.DataAsJson',
    responseHandler: function (res) {
        res.jsonData
    },
```

Can anyone see why this would happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got to the bottom of this in case someone else gets caught by it.

I modified the js to read the model data as following:

```
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
data: @Html.Raw(Model.DataAsJson)
```

So I removed the apostrophes and added the Html.Raw.  I realised this by viewing the data in Chrome debugger and could see it was encoded.  Also, I was having some further issues as the legacy codebase I am working with had the script in a partial view and the Chrome debugger was not hitting the debug points.  I sorted this by adding:

```
debugger;
```

where I wanted it to break.

Thanks and hope this helps others.